# How to insert picture id to database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I got a form with picture and submit button, which sends the user_id of the connected user and picture_id of the picture that they want to save into the table called pins in MySQL Database. I tried to pin different pictures from different users. Insert of user_id works  but the picture_id  stays the same(the last picture in pictures table) even though I click on submit below different pictures. Is it because of the form, or am I referring to it in a wrong way?

Im placing here the php code with the picture and the button to save it.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__.'/connect.php';
$sUsername = $_SESSION['txtUsername'];

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM pictures INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id = pictures.user_id');
    $stmt->execute();
    $aRows = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($aRows as $aRow) {echo 
    "<form action='display.php' method='POST'>
    <div class=item><img src=images/$aRow->path>
    <span class=caption>Picture id:$aRow->picture_id</span>
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
    </div>
    </form>";}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = :sUserName');
        $stmt->bindValue(':sUserName', $sUsername);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        $iUserId = $row->user_id;

        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO pins VALUES( null, :iUserId, :iPictureId )');
        $stmt->bindValue(':iUserId', $iUserId);
        $stmt->bindValue(':iPictureId', $aRow->picture_id);
        $stmt->execute();
      }catch (PDOEXception $ex){
        echo $ex;
      }
    }
  }catch (PDOEXception $ex){
    echo $ex;
  }

?>
```